# InstantiationException only in release apk

Tags: android

Application is crashing on launch. Debug apk is working fine but release apk is facing this issue. Can anyone help?

```
03-29 10:22:55.725 31420-31420/np.com.drac.ghtweather E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: np.com.drac.ghtweather, PID: 31420
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application np.com.drac.ghtweather.GHTapp: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<np.com.drac.ghtweather.GHTapp> cannot be instantiated
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:977)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<np.com.drac.ghtweather.GHTapp> cannot be instantiated
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1093)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:971)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6030) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: did u use option build apk to build ur release apk?

Comment: Kaveesh I changed build variant to release and run on my phone.

Comment: can you show what happens in the init of the `GHTapp` class?

Comment: disable Instant run and then build the apk in release mode using the below mentioned approach.

Answer (score 0):

To build release apk in newer android studio versions,first of all disable instant run and then select 
"Build"->"Build APK(s)" option and then build your apk for it to run properly.

This is the proper way to build an apk. Try this and let me know if it works or not. 
After you do this android studio will prompt you a link which will point to the file location of your apk.

Comment: Done but still same issue.

Comment: disable Instant run and then build the apk in release using the above mentioned approach.

Answer (score 0):

**Check the release  mode**

```
 if( BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("release")) {

 }
```

**Check the debug mode**

```
 if( BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("debug")) {

 }
```

**OR**

check your menifest xml

```
 <application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:name=".YourApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/your_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

**OR**

```
  buildTypes {
    release {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
   'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }
```

try  this code i have faced the same problem it is my solution to resolve the problem i hope it helps you.

Comment: Where you want me to put the above code? My manifest is same though.

    <application xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:name=".GHTapp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        tools:replace="android:theme, allowBackup">

Comment: try this in gradel